# Store does not have reducer initialState

Tags: react-native, redux, state, store

I cannot get the store reducer initialState, so I cannot map to props in the component as well.

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = { currentUser: null }

export default function UserReducer(state = initialState, action){
   let nextState;
   switch(action.type){
    case "USER_CONNECTED":
        nextState = {
            ...state,
            currentUser : action.value
        }
        return nextState;
    case "USER_DECONNECTED":
        nextState = {
            ...state,
            currentUser : null
        }
        return nextState;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Here is the class that configures the store:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserReducer from './reducers/userReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    currentUser : UserReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
}

export default configureStore;
```

And here is where I initialise the store and pass it to the App thanks to a provider:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/store';


const Store = configureStore();
console.log("STORE :"+ JSON.stringify(Store.getState()));
const RNRedux = () => (

    <Provider store = { Store }>
      <App />
    </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

When I print the "STORE" above, it gives me the right output ***{ currentUser  : ...}***. Then I connect App.js to the store as follows:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    NewAccount: NewAccountScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen
},
{
    initialRouteName: "Login"
}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context){
      super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
      console.log("APP.JS : "+ JSON.stringify(this.props));
      return (
        <AppContainer />
      )
    }
  }

  export default connect()(App);
```

So at the last line I connect the entire App state to the component props but it gives me ***{}***.

Comment: you are missing getState() function call i think.. try JSON.stringify(Store.getState()) . the createStore returns a store instance that has a getState and dispatch functions. use getState to retrieve current state

Comment: I'm sorry, let me edit my question.

Comment: now you are missing mapStateToProps param in your connect call. you need to specify mapping function that will take parts of state and pass it to components props. to map entire state to props try this: export default connect(state=>state)(App)

Comment: It works, perfect. Write an answer, I'll mark it as the right answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `mapStateToProps` param in your connect call.

```
export default connect()(App);
```

You need to specify mapping function that will take parts of state and pass it to components props. 
To map entire state to props try this:

```
export default connect(state=>state)(App)
```

Better practice would be to pass only parts of state that the component needs. That way you would avoid unnecessary re-renders when some other part of state changes. For example if your connected component only needs user first name you could do this:

```
export default connect(state=>{firstName:state.currentUser.firstName})(App)
```